# avoidance dfrobot arduino code with switch

Tags: arduino

Can someone provide me with arduino code for avoidance robot where the robot stops and turns right if the obtstacle is on the left and vice versa.

I am using dfrobot miniq discovery kit.
Please I need a code with switch cases such as forward, stop, turn

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is just asking for code and shows no effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use if...else instead of switch. No obstacle within the range of 300cm it stops, if available runs forward, obstacle on range of 20-40 it turns right. This is for ultrasonic sensor.

```
 #define trig 13
 #define echo 12
 void setup()
 {
 pinMode(2,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(3,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(4,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(5,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(6,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(7,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(12,INPUT);
 pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
 Serial.begin(9600);
 digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
 digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
 }
void loop()
{
 int a,b;

 digitalWrite(trig,LOW);
 delayMicroseconds(10);
 digitalWrite(trig,HIGH);
 delayMicroseconds(10);
 digitalWrite(trig,LOW);

 a=pulseIn(echo,HIGH);
 b=a/29.1;
 if(b<300 && b>0)
 {
 //Run forward
  digitalWrite(4,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(5,LOW);
  digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(7,LOW);

 if(b>20 && b<40)
 {

 //turn right
  digitalWrite(4,LOW);
  digitalWrite(5,LOW);
  digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(7,LOW);
 }
 else
 {

 //stops
  digitalWrite(4,LOW);
  digitalWrite(5,LOW);
  digitalWrite(6,LOW);
  digitalWrite(7,LOW);
  }
  }
 }
```